# WooCommerce - Related Products by ALL product's tags

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, tags, product

I need to make a customization, maybe create a new function and add it to related.php, which will do the following task: 
fetch the related products that will have all 3 product’s tags of that specific product when I visit the single product page.

Let me give you an example: lets say I have a pair of sunglasses with the following tags: round, female, plastic. The current configuration, fetches sunglasses or eyeglasses that may have a tag of female, or plastic, or round.

What I need is to fetch related products that will have all 3 tags, for example, related products that will have round AND female AND plastic as tags.

Any advices? Maybe a plugin that will do the work?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: used this plugin  https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-related-products-for-woocommerce/

Comment: Hi Ankur and thank you for your suggestion. I am aware of this plugin but it needs to go to every single product, one-by-one, and set the related products for each product. I need something that will not need this procedure.